# The book Entity Framework Vol 2. What parts are now out of date

Tags: entity-framework

This, to me, is a programming question.

For anyone wanting a good book on entity framework the o'reilly book 'Entity Framework' still seems like a good option (that's the subjective part). The entity framework has moved on so are there any parts of this book now considered completely out of date? I mean this from a chapter point of view rather than detailed

Comment: You could ask the author: http://thedatafarm.com/contact/

Comment: A bit of digging and the answer is on that site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://thedatafarm.com/book/after-3-years-devs-are-still-finding-programming-entity-framework-2ed-useful/

"... the 2nd edition. After that Microsoft released DbContext (which sits on top of the ObjectContext for simpler coding) and Code First that sat on top of EF4. EF5 was mostly a consolidation that also took advantage of 3 new features in .NET 4.5 (enums, spatial data and query caching). VS2012 brought some nice designer improvements and a default DbContext/POCO code generator. EF6 mostly adds some advanced features to what’s already there.

But what hasn’t changed much are things like LINQ to Entities, security, ESQL, how transactions work (small change coming in EF6), databinding, code generation,and most importantly the Entity Framework internals. It is understanding the internals that give you real power over Entity Framework – not relying on the #efhelp hashtag, stackoverflow or the kindness of strangers."